# Qt not receiving QGesture events

Tags: c++, qt

I've been trying to get gesture events on Qt, but my program only recognizes mouse events when I interact with it.

This is the example code I've written:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    grabGesture(Qt::SwipeGesture);
}

bool MainWindow::event(QEvent *e){

    if (e->type() == QEvent::Gesture) {
        std::cout << "got a gesture" << std::endl;
    }

    return QWidget::event(e);

}
```

I've read the documentation, either I'm not understanding what a gesture event is, or there are some other commands needed to enable it that I haven't found...

I am using Xfce 4.10, and Qt 5.3.2 .

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try to set `setAttribute(Qt::WA_AcceptTouchEvents);`

Comment: Just tried it, and it didn't work unfortunately.